# running java code on different JDK and different results appear

Tags: java

In my java code I use a LinkedHashMap to store data and at the end I remove duplicates and sort parts of data and the result is fine, what I need. Using JDK 1.6 
However, running the same code on a different Linux server with JDK 1.5 gives a different result. For instance it doesnt sort the elements of LinkedHashMap for me or maybe the Collections dont work. 
I would really appreciate your advice.

Comment: This question is too vague. We need to see your code, there is plenty of things that could be going wrong with no difference between the JDKs.

Comment: different how? doesn't sort or maybe something else?

Answer (score 1):

How are you sorting it? A `LinkedHashMap` is not a sorted map, rather it just maintains insertion order. If you need a map that iterates in a sorted order, you should use a `TreeMap`.
Depending on how you are doing the sort, the ordering of the map may be different if you're using a `LinkedHashMap` since the JDKs may sort it slightly differently.

Comment: Dear Jeff, Thanks for your comments, well I dont try to sort the elements of LinkedHashMap, when I am outputting I try to sort few elements in a proper order and then output, have a look on my output : ?,1,?,?,3,2,213,?,?,?,?,1,?,1,?,?,?,?,?,2,no --- When I run the code on my own machine I properly get 123 instead of 213, while running it on the server with older JDK it produces this result. I believe there is not a problem with the code, I just guess that JDK is the trouble because I get the answer I want on my own system

Comment: Can you post the code? It's near impossible to offer any specific help with just the description you have provided?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, But the problem was not with the code as it was running fine on my own machine. I installed jdk1.6.0_33 locally on the linux server and the code works fine now. Seems that some of java built in methods may not work properly in older jdks.